# Creation of encryption keys with new policy with AWS Cli/Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I created a new policy using policy generator on AWS. I am trying to create a key using that policy but Im getting this error:

> "" BypassPolicyLockoutSafetyCheck = False   File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py",
>   line 253, in _api_call
>       return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py",
>   line 543, in _make_api_call
>       raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name) botocore.errorfactory.MalformedPolicyDocumentException: An error
>   occurred (MalformedPolicyDocumentException) when calling the CreateKey
>   operation: ""

I have validated the format of key and I know there is no issue in syntax. Here is the policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1489675746111",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "workspaces:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1489675786111",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "kms:CreateAlias",
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:CreateKey",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:DeleteAlias",
            "kms:DescribeKey",
            "kms:EnableKey",
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey",
            "kms:GetKeyPolicy",
            "kms:ListAliases",
            "kms:ListGrants",
            "kms:ListKeyPolicies",
            "kms:ListKeys",
            "kms:PutKeyPolicy"    
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1489675858111",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreatePolicy",
            "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
            "iam:DeletePolicy",
            "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
            "iam:GetPolicy",
            "iam:GetPolicyVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]}
```

I am using python to create the key. If I am using the default policy then I am able to create the policy. Any have any idea about this? some real-time example? I have looked around in aws documentation but could not find any good example related to aws cli.

```
response = kms.create_key(
      Policy = 'KeyPolicyForScripting',
      Description = 'Workspaces Key',
      KeyUsage = 'ENCRYPT_DECRYPT',
      Origin = 'AWS_KMS',
      BypassPolicyLockoutSafetyCheck = False
)
```

Comment: Insufficient rights. A cheating ways to find out is create a dummy user and give it a console rights, login and try to use the KMS and tackle each access denied error.

Comment: I am not sure if its the rights issue. Because I can create a key with with default policy. Secondly, I have tried running Policy simulator and It does show I have the access and right. But I will try your way, nothing to lose.